# Bookshelf query to update table

Tags: sql, node.js, npm, bookshelf.js

I tried searching but no hint to bookshelf query equivalent to this one

```
update <Table Name> set <Column> x = y where z = a;
```

Thanks.

Comment: down votes are welcomed if accompanied by comments to improve.
Learning is always important than stack reputation.

Comment: I think whoever down voted did not like your question's lack of research. Have you really gone through Bookshelf's documentation? The question will be more useful if you add sample code demoing your attempt.

Comment: Thanks @flaviodesousa . this is what i needed. i didn't add details as i want it to be generic. your answer is also very generic and can help other newbie like me. THANKS ONCE AGAIN!!!. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bookshelf [`save()` documentation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-save) has an example for exactly that.

Just use `where()` on the Model to specify which rows and `save()` with the list of attributes along with the `{ patch: true }` option.

If we have a table *users(id,name,email)* it will be something like:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {filename: 'data.sqlite3'},
  debug: true}); // <- so you can see the generated query
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
});

(function() {
  User
    .where({name:'amy'})
    .save({email: 'amysnewemail@example.com'},{patch:true})
    .then(function(x) {
      console.log(x.toJSON());
    });
})();
```

The code above produces as output:

```
{ method: 'update',
  options: {},
  bindings: [ 'amysnewemail@example.com', 'amy' ],
  sql: 'update "users" set "email" = ? where "name" = ?' }
{ email: 'amysnewemail@example.com' }
```